# Как уменьшить звук audio html

Tags: javascript, html

Есть автовоспроизведение звука на сайте

```
<audio controls src="bgsound.mp3" autoplay="autoplay"></audio>
```

Как уменьшить громкость звука без участия пользователя. Звук очень громкий, потому надо его сделать потише по умолчанию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь свойством volume, у элемента audio

```
var audio=document.querySelector("audio");
audio.volume=0.5;
```

Comment: Спасибо! Всё работает!